# how to adjust audio level across multiple editors?

Tags: audio-recording, levels

Alright, so this is a tough one for me to word in a google search, and I'm somewhat new to audio engineering.

A video was shot, not by me, and the audio was monitored, also not by me. I edited the video and then it was sent to YouTube, the viewers are complaining of low audio levels. So, I took the clip back into our editor and raised the level's to 6 DB, the loudest it'd let me go. The viewers are still complaining. Even though tests in house from multiple devices show the levels are good.

Is there a way for me to throw this video into other editors to continue raising the volume?

I understand that there will be an enormous amount of feedback and it won't sound good, I've tried telling the powers that be that this is not a good idea.

Comment: At what level is your audio peaking?

Comment: looks like you need to use a compressor for your audio content

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to edit the audio in an audio editor. Assuming that is so...

1: check there aren't strong levels below 100Hz (low bass rumble). If there are, remove them with an EQ or High Pass Filter.

2: normalise the file, which is usually a one-click operation in any editor. It means 'make the file as loud as it can be without clipping'.

3: if still not loud enough, apply a compressor and if you don't know what you're doing, use a preset called 'voice-over' or something like that.

4: Hopefully the compressor made it louder (presets usually make use of 'makeup' which raises the gain after applying compression). If it didn't, normalise the file again.

Listen carefully to the results, and check for distortion. If it sounds fuzzy, harsh or generally horrible, you're probably applying too much compression.

Answer (score 0):

Get a DAW like Fl studio or Ableton live or even the free audacity, export your audio into the DAW and use its compression plugin to raise the gain of your audio. for example, in Fl studio, use the 'fruity limiter' to raise the gain.

Answer (score 0):

If your struggling with this it sounds like the audio was not recorded very well at all. It shouldn't be that hard even without an audio editor.